# Text Box and Message Box

Tags: c#

I know this looks a stupid question, I am new to C# and I wanna know, How do I make a Message Box with a text according with what I wrote in the text box.

**Example:**
*I Wrote "Hi" in the Text box, and if I click a button, it will show a message box saying "Hello"*
**Another Example:**
*I Wrote "Whats your name" in the text box, I pressed the button, and it will show a message box saying "My name is..."*

So, It will show a message box with a text **RELATED** with what I wrote in the text box, but not the same text that I wrote in the text box.

Well, I tried to explain in the most easy way, if you understood what I mean, please help me how can I do something like that.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow! Please add the framework you're working with, like ASP.Net or MVC. The controls and how you work with them differs. Also, please add some code what you already tried.

Comment: Well you will have to write a relation engine that knows what the right message will be, according to the text in the box. It might be called `string messageFromText(string text)`..

Comment: Exactly what is it you are having a problem with? Creating a textbox to input text? Showing the response? Figuring out the response? Are you using winforms or WPF? If you are new to c# a good first step is to follow some tutorial about creating a simple UI.

Answer (score 0):

```
MessasgeBox.Show(TextBox.Text, "custom title")
```

Hope that might help!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please fix the syntax `MessasgeBox`